# Short story I read years ago (1971?) about a planet of machines that find a stray American astronaut

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, astronauts

The machines are speaking to the astronaut inside the capsule.  However, they think they are speaking to the capsule because they had never seen a human before.  When they try to open it up, they remove a burned blob of flesh, and are amazed that the controls are so simplistic and unsophisticated.  They are baffled that the machine has stopped communicating with them.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135127/robots-on-planet-with-no-humans-until-a-rocket-with-a-human-lands, also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175686/name-of-vintage-sci-fi-horror-short-story-collection/175687#175687

Comment: @DoscoJones I agree that's the answer, are you going to post it?

Answer (score 7):

["Lost Memory"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58142) by [Peter Phillips](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?122468), first published in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, May 1952](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58588+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v04n02_1952-05#page/n45/mode/2up).

Looks like a duplicate of [Robots on planet with no humans until a rocket with a human lands](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135127/robots-on-planet-with-no-humans-until-a-rocket-with-a-human-lands).